# Vaadin Flow: How to add border to Dialog / Confirm Dialog?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I would like to add border and contrast to a Vaadin Dialog / ConfirmDialog.

Doing the following:

```java
ConfirmDialog dlg = new ConfirmDialog();
dlg.addClassNames(LumoUtility.Border.ALL, LumoUtility.BorderColor.CONTRAST);
```

Unfortunately this adds the border to the canvas (basically the whole screen) rather than to the overlay which is the actual dialog.

Background: What I want to "correct" in the standard Lumo theme is that when using the Dark Theme there's too little of a contrast between the Dialog and its background, which makes it difficult to see where one begins and other other one ends.

Using Vaadin Flow v23.2.4.

### Final solution

As per Vaadin's documentation the overlay cannot be styled using CSS class names and therefore cannot be styled using Java. In my case it is acceptable to have my new style apply to *every* ConfirmDialog that the application uses.

Following [Jouni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74070399/1504556), I did the following:

In the `frontend/themes/my-theme/components` folder I added a file named `vaadin-confirm-dialog-overlay.css`  with content as follows:

```css
/* Customize ConfirmDialog so that it has a border.
   If not, the dialog tends to blend in with the background
   in particular when using Dark theme.
 */
vaadin-confirm-dialog-overlay::part(overlay) {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--lumo-contrast-50pct);
}
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to style the “overlay” part of the Dialog component.

```css
vaadin-dialog-overlay::part(overlay) {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

See the documentation for some more info: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/getting-started/#styling.get-started.sub-component-styling

As a side note, you should also make sure you're applying the dark theme to the `<html theme="dark">` element, instead of `<body theme="dark">`. When you set the attribute on the `<body>` element, the shadow colors are not updated correctly, and that makes the contrast between the overlay elements and the main background less apparent.

Comment: I apply the dark theme using `@Theme(value = "myapp", variant = Lumo.DARK)` on my SpringBoot app main class. There _is_ contrast, but not enough for my taste. I'll have a look at the link. It seems I cannot do it with Java only?

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying that. Yeah, not possible to do all styling with Java.